# Using Regex, how can I pull out the top-level domain name?

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to create ONE efficient regular expression (least amount of backtracking) to pull out the top-level domain name from some logs.  The URL could be one of four types, so I need the following:

1. extract **website.ca** in **"website.ca/somepage"**
2. extract **website.com** in **"https://subdomain.website.com/somepage"**
3. extract **10.10.10.10** in **"10.10.10.10/somepage"**
4. extract **myserver** in **"myserver/somepage"**

I have a semi-working solution, but it misses some.

```
"[^"]*(\w+\.[a-z]+|\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\/
```

Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Why dont you simply `split` the `string` by `/` and take the first element of it?

Comment: This is in a SIEM system so it's not really a scripting/programming environment.  It just uses the Java regex engine to parse logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9\.]+|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?=\/)
```

You can test it at regex101.com: https://regex101.com/r/dK0bJ7/4

MATCH 1: `website.com`
MATCH 2: `10.10.10.10`
MATCH 3: `myserver`
MATCH 4: `website.ca`

Comment: It works well for the others, but it matches too much on "https://subdomain.website.com/somepage".  I just want the top-level domain name.

Comment: Sorry, I have not read your question carefully enough. I have updated my answer. Now, it should give the desired output

Comment: Why is there alternation: `.[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9\.]+` ? Why not type `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` ? This would handle website.c9a too.

Comment: @tamasrev: For all I know (I may be wrong here), top-level domains consists of characters only (com, edu, biz, de,...). Therefore, I have explicitly excluded numbers. I guess adding 0-9 would do no harm either...